# Finding coefficients that impose symmetry

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, permutation

To simplify the main question below,consider the following random multivariate polynomial :

```
c = 0;
r = 4; l = 5;
vars = x^RandomInteger[r, l]*y^RandomInteger[r, l];
expression = 
 Total@Map[(c++; a[c]*#) &]@
   DeleteDuplicates@Join[vars, vars /. {x -> y, y -> x}]
```

`x y^4 a[1] + x y a[2] + x^4 y^2 a[3] + y^4 a[4] + x^2 a[5] +  x^4 y a[6] + x^2 y^4 a[7] + x^4 a[8] + y^2 a[9]`

In LaTeX :

$$ a(3) x^4 y^2+a(6) x^4 y+a(8) x^4+a(7) x^2 y^4+a(5) x^2+a(1) x y^4+a(2) x y+a(4) y^4+a(9) y^2 $$

If all the coefficients were 1 then the polynomial above would be symmetric with respect to the permutation : $x \leftrightarrow y$. But there is a less restrictive choice of coefficients which is:

`a[1]=a[6],a[3]=a[7],a[4]=a[8],a[9]=a[5]`

In the past I used [`FindPermutation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPermutation.html) on the list of constants after switching `x` with `y` but I remember it being a bit of a pain to code. Is there another way ?

---

Bob Hanlon's answer works quite well even in the more general case I am considering with dot products and products. Here is another way directly inspired from Bob Hanlon's code but it does not sort the list of equations (for my application it is not necessary that the list is sorted):

```
f[x_, y_] = 
  x y^4 a[1] + x y a[2] + x^4 y^2 a[3] + y^4 a[4] + x^2 a[5] + 
   x^4 y a[6] + x^2 y^4 a[7] + x^4 a[8] + y^2 a[9];
```

Note: • is a unicode character used to distinguish from system functions using CamelCase

```
•SymRule=
(
(
    Flatten@CoefficientList[f[x,y],{x,y}]
                    ==
    Flatten@CoefficientList[f[y,x],{x,y}]
)
// Thread
// DeleteCases[True]
// DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]
// ReplaceAll[Equal->Rule]
)
```

then:

```
f[x, y] - f[y, x] /. •SymRule
```

`0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that [`ForAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll.html) may help to define the statement that you want. Using [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) to find the simpler coefficient statement

```
List@@Sort[
    Reduce[
        ForAll[{x,y}, f[x, y]==f[y, x] ]
    ]
]
```

[image]

Or using [`SolveAlways`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html) apparently more conveniently for the OP (as per a comment bellow)

```
SolveAlways[f[x, y] == f[y, x], {x, y}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very Nice. Thank you for your answer and for giving me the opportunity to use `ForAll`. I checked the examples on `ForAll` and the magic of Mathematica's documentation leads to `SolveAlways` as the last example in the properties and relations section. That then leads to the one liner `SolveAlways[f[x, y] == f[y, x], {x, y}]` which I found thanks to your answer.

Comment: It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. Users should test answers before voting and wait at least 24 hours before accepting, so you give an oportunity to answer to people around the many time zones.

Comment: I noticed one drawback of this method which is that it only seems to work with variables that are `AtomQ` if I am not mistaken, in particular it does not work with the following list of variables `{w . x, w . y, x . x, x . y, y . y}` but Bob Hanlon's method does (I have to also use `TensorReduce`). In any case I will just accept whatever answer gets the most points as my question only involves `AtomQ` variables.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] = 
  x y^4 a[1] + x y a[2] + x^4 y^2 a[3] + y^4 a[4] + x^2 a[5] + 
   x^4 y a[6] + x^2 y^4 a[7] + x^4 a[8] + y^2 a[9];

cond = Union[
  Sort /@ (Thread[Flatten[CoefficientList[f[x, y], {x, y}]] ==
       Flatten[CoefficientList[f[y, x], {x, y}]]] /. 
    True -> Nothing)]

(* {a[1] == a[6], a[3] == a[7], a[4] == a[8], a[5] == a[9]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
Assuming[cond, f[x, y] == f[y, x] // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

Comment: This is quite nice.  It makes my last ideas I had of building a matrix from the coefficient rules and equating upper and lower triangles seem silly.

Comment: @userrandrand - I used the `Sort` to put the equations in canonical order, e.g., `a[9] == a[5]` and `a[5] == a[9]` are made the same. `Union` removes the duplicates like `DeleteDuplicates` but also sorts the equations.

Comment: ahh so it's to render `Equal` orderless when applying `Union`. Nice.